Compute can't handle <NA> values in column that hat a float dtype in a dask dataframe
Every time I try to compute the dataframe it fails giving me the following or similar error messages:
Exception: 'ValueError("could not convert string to float: \'<NA>\'")'
Right now, I want to filter out all rows that contain float values. This works, but once I want to write it back to disk as a parquet file and call compute() during it, it fails (the writing to disk works when not calling compute). I have tried replacing  with numpy.nan, I have tried converting the columns to numeric, I have tried replacing all 'NA' and '' strings and to fill all empty values unsing fillna(), but all to no avail.
Has anybody encountered a similar error or know how to fix it?

This will be difficult to debug without a reproducible example...

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Since dask has started to assume config value dataframe.dtype_backend="arrow" as default, columns that start off as "object" pandas type are automatically converted to "string[pyarrow]" type. This is because the most common contents of a pandas object column is strings, but (as you now know) this is not always the case. The attempted conversion happens before your data would be passed to any further tasks, which is why you are failing to replace the values.
So: you can give details of where the data came from, or set the config value to "numpy_nullable".
The rest of the question regarding compute() does not make much sense without seeing what you have tried to do, I'm afraid.
